# How to execute jquery inside category.php which should work for each individual post in category wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to execute a onclick event on div of each post in category with the help of jquery. How can I execute it.

I assign the value of div id  dynamically as **answer_postid** 
for example post 1 has post id 01 so its div id="answer_01"
and post 2nd has post id 02, so its div id="answer_02"

Now I want to hide all the divs of each post inside category when document is completely loaded 
and also want to execute onclick event on a element a with id **viewanswer_postid**
different posts contains `<a>` with  different id as viewanswer_o1, viewanswer_02......

I tried by putting script in content.php
doesn't work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div#answer_<?php echo get_the_ID();?>").hide();    
});
</script>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header page-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="entry-meta text-muted">
        <?php ipt_kb_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <table class="mcqtable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><?php echo '<a id="index_A_'.get_the_ID ().'" href="javascript: void 0;">A.</a>';?>
                <td class="option"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'option_A', true); ?></td>
                <td class="index"><?php echo '<a id="index_B_'.get_the_ID ().'" href="javascript: void 0;">B.</a>';?>
                <td class="option"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'option_B', true); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><?php echo '<a id="index_C_'.get_the_ID ().'" href="javascript: void 0;">C.</a>';?>
                <td class="option"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'option_C', true); ?></td>
                <td class="index"><?php echo '<a id="index_D_'.get_the_ID ().'" href="javascript: void 0;">D.</a>';?>
                <td class="option"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'option_D', true); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="view_answer_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" href="javascript: void 0;">View Answer</a>
    <div id="answer_<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
        <?php echo 'Correct Answer is: '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'option_correct', true); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => __( '<p class="pagination-p">Pages:</p>', 'ipt_kb' ) . '<ul class="pagination">',
            'after'  => '</ul><div class="clearfix"></div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<footer class="entry-meta text-muted well well-sm">
    <?php
        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
        $category_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'ipt_kb' ) );

        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
        $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'ipt_kb' ) );

        if ( ! ipt_kb_categorized_blog() ) {
            // This blog only has 1 category so we just need to worry about tags in the meta text
            if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was tagged <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%2$s. <br />Bookmark the <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%3$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ipt_kb' );
            } else {
                $meta_text = __( 'Bookmark the <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%3$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ipt_kb' );
            }

        } else {
            // But this blog has loads of categories so we should probably display them here
            if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%1$s and tagged <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%2$s. <br />Bookmark the <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%3$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ipt_kb' );
            } else {
                $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;%1$s. <br />Bookmark the <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%3$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ipt_kb' );
            }

        } // end check for categories on this blog

        printf(
            $meta_text,
            $category_list,
            $tag_list,
            get_permalink()
        );
    ?>

    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'ipt_kb' ), '<span class="edit-link"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;', '</span>' ); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery code inside the loop?

That's not a very good technique.

Why not assign a `class="answer"` to each answer div and then use

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.answer').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**outside of the loop?**

Also, it would be more helpful if you posted one plain HTML example, to see exactly what's wrong (every theme has a different structure, so saying *content.php* isn't much helpful). Hope this helps.